# restore commit lost due to "git fetch && git checkout"

Tags: git, svn, bitbucket

I use git (bitbucket) for versioning. I want to do push the project to the server. I do like this:

```
git add.
git commit -m "view almost finished"
git push
```

I found a fatal error. I assume probably because there is no branch in my repository. so I created a branch. then I did a command like the following.

```
git fetch && git checkout  create-view
git push
```

then, all new files become disappeared. I try to search from the git log, but I do not find the last commit.

how to restore my last commit due to "git fetch && git checkout"?

Comment: In future, if you get "fatal error", make sure to copy the verbatim error message here so that we can better understand the whole situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have switched to `create-view` branch. That is the reason you are not able to see your changes. To switch back to the `master` just run,

```
git checkout master
```

Hopefully all your changes should be back. If you branch was with some other name. Just check for `git branch`, this will list all your local branches. You should then be able to switch using,

```
git checkout <branch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you committed locally to another branch (maybe master) instead of create-view branch. That is why you can't see your commit.

You have 2 options:

1) Go back to the previous branch you were on and see if the commit is there. If yes, you can `git cherry-pick` that commit into to create-view branch and then push.

2) You can use `git reflog show` find the commit id for the local commit and `git cherry-pick` that commit into to create-view branch and then push.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following in your terminal:

```
**git reflog**
```

this shows you a history of all your branches with their commit numbers etc
then:

```
**git checkout yourbranchname**
```

followed by

```
**git reset --hard yourmaincommitcode**//eg 532b7662
```

Here is a tutorial on this issue.It helped me in my novice days when i performed ***“git fetch && git checkout”*** in my android studio terminal without understanding what it meant,and all my files disappeared in android studio aswell as my project folder.
[Recovering Lost Commits with git reflog and reset](http://effectif.com/git/recovering-lost-git-commits)